# Execute internal code on build

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, build

#### Background

In an ASP.NET site, I'm using a code documentation tool called [Nocco](https://github.com/dontangg/nocco).  Nocco is a command line tool that you explicitly run on a particular code file to output an HTML rendered version of that code and it's documentation.  I've currently setup some code in my `Global_asax.Application_Start` method to crawl through a couple directories and process all the code files in each directory.

#### Problem

Ultimately, putting it in `Global_asax.Applicaton_Start` means that it is building the Nocco documentation, which takes ~1 seconds per file, at the beginning of each session - not only once per deployment.  This seems inefficient and an ultimate waste of the user's time while the page is loading.

#### Question

Is it possible to execute code internal to the ASP.NET application (such as a class method) as a post build event?  I know that I could convert this part of my setup to a standalone application or even a batch script, but I've had this question for other circumstances as well and have wondered whether or not it's possible.

Comment: why do you wont to keep documentation generation in ASP.NET app ?

Comment: @AntonioBakula As I said, I know that there are different ways of accomplishing what I'm describing.  But I'm asking if there's some mechanism to do this that will generate the documentation once for each build, not using the session start and `Application_Start` methods - specifically using methods internal to my application, not external programs.

Comment: @AntonioBakula To more directly answer your question, I want to keep documentation generation in ASP.NET because I'm serving the documentation along side the app (in fact, it's incorporated into the app itself).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do your generation in Warm up script, here is the link for IIS 7.5

http://blogs.iis.net/thomad/archive/2009/10/14/now-available-the-iis-7-5-application-warm-up-module.aspx

or you can exclude code documentation functionality in separate assembly and include it in standalone app and call it as a external command from project Build events